# Can Google Analytics analyze usage of my Google Play app page?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-play-store

It is possible to configure a [Google Analytics UA](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts) for a Google Code project.
Similarly, is it possible to configure a Google Analytics UA for [a Google Play app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki)?

Context:
The current trend for app developers is to market/link/print their Google Play URL directly, rather than their own website's URL.
While this make it easier for users to install the app (one less click), this removes the webmaster's ability to analyze where visitors are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is impossible now, because if you want to use Google Analytics first you have to upload a specific-named file to your host, so Google understands who  you are and it stores your data.

Google Play is not your area; you only have profile.

Comment: I wish they will let us upload a UA file in the future. This becomes very important for efficient Android marketing.

Comment: It's actually sorta ridiculous they dont have the same feature in the Google play store as the their "chrome store". In the Chrome store google gives you a text field in the developer console where you can put the UA id number in there to track its "app page" using google analytics.